# expo-google-app-auth not redirecting back to app after successful sign in

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-signin

Am learning expo by trying to build a small app which i use google for auth, i have followed all the instructions in the expo docs, but still can't figure why the app redirects to google.com after i click sign in with google and selection one of gmail accounts.

```
import React, { createContext,useContext } from "react";
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';
import { GoogleAuthProvider,onAuthStateChanged,signInWithCredential,signOut } from "@firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const AuthContext = createContext({})
const config = {
    iosClientId:"id",
    androidClientId:"id",
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    permissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'gender', 'location'],
    redirectUrl: `host.exp.exponent:/oauth2redirect/google`
};
export const AuthProvider=({children})=>{
    const signInWithGoogle = async ()=>{
         await Google.logInAsync(config).then(async (logInResult)=>{
            console.log(logInResult);
            if(logInResult.type==='success'){
                console.log(logInResult);
                const {idToken,accessToken}=logInResult;
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken,accessToken);
                await signInWithCredential(auth,credential);
            }else{
                return Promise.reject(); 
            }
         });
         
           
        
    };
    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider
         value={{
             user:null,
             signInWithGoogle,
             }}>
           {children} 
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default function useAuth(){
```

return  useContext(AuthContext)
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running the app on a physical device, unfortunately this error is occurs on emulators